# Custom Realm for ObjectDB, using ObjectDB with HTTP Basic authentication

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, realm, object-oriented-database, objectdb

I want to implement HTTP Basic Authentication for my web services, but I also want to use ObjectDB to store credentials. Is there any way to do this? I guess I'm in the need of a custom realm, and also, that somebody already did this before, so if yes please raise your hands. Otherwise please help me with the implementation. I already checked the basics of making custom realms. Is it possible somehow to make it work with JDBCRealm, or more directly, is it possible to create a JDBC resource in GlassFish that uses the ObjectDB server?

What I did so far is the base of the `Realm`:

```
package objectdbrealm;

import com.sun.appserv.security.AppservRealm;
import com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.BadRealmException;
import com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.InvalidOperationException;
import com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.NoSuchRealmException;
import com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.NoSuchUserException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ObjectDbRealm extends AppservRealm {

    @Override
    public void init(Properties properties) throws BadRealmException, NoSuchRealmException {
        //initialize the realm
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthType() {
        return "ObjectDB Realm";
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration getGroupNames(String string) throws InvalidOperationException, NoSuchUserException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

, and `LoginModule`:

```
package objectdbrealm;

import com.sun.appserv.security.AppservPasswordLoginModule;
import com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException;

public class ObjectDbLoginModule extends AppservPasswordLoginModule {

    @Override
    protected void authenticateUser() throws LoginException {
        if (!authenticate(_username, _passwd)) {
            //Login fails
            throw new LoginException((new StringBuilder()).append("Login Failed for:").append(_username).toString());
        }
        String[] groups = getGroupNames(_username);
        commitUserAuthentication(groups);
    }

    private boolean authenticate(String username, char[] password) {
        /*
        Check the credentials against the authentication source,
        return true if authenticated, return false otherwise
         */
        return true;
    }

    private String[] getGroupNames(String username) {
        // Return the list of groups this user belongs to.
        return new String[0];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Sadly [it turned out](http://www.objectdb.com/database/forum/271) that there is no JDBC driver for ObjectDB yet. Feel free to make suggestions however!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It turned out](http://www.objectdb.com/database/forum/271) that there is no `JDBCDriver` for ObjectDB yet. I've found it too much to implement my own, so I will just wait :)

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but there's the excellent [FlexibleJDBCRealm](http://flexiblejdbcrealm.wamblee.org/site/) that offers an alternative to the rather rigid JDBCRealm that comes with the Fish.  It's open source,  adapting that code to ObjectDB should be a lot easier than starting to implement a realm from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

JDBC is not mandatory is you are using Objectdb. You can create a Stateless EJB in your project that access your ObjectDb entities to perform the login validation.The your method

> private boolean authenticate(String username, char[] password) 
>   can use an EJB client to perform the credentials validations.
>   This [example](https://computingat40s.wordpress.com/how-to-create-a-custom-realm-in-glassfish-3-1-2-2/) worked fine for me. The only change to make is using your ObjectDb entities for the datamodel and as an improvement you can put the interface IUserAuthenticationService in a separate jar to avoid distributing the implementation.

Hope that helps.

Rn